# Add items to list in existing multiprocessing pool map

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have an existing multiprocessing pool map which will execute an api call , but each api call return an item which should be added to one list from all of the each processes.

```
file_list = []
#this list will have approx million records

pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count(),initializer=init_pool, initargs=(token,url))

pool.map(find_violations, file_list)
```

The function which run in pool:

```
def find_violations(file):

    #executes api call
    return response
```

I should add this response to one list from all of each processes.
I know that we should add manager list , but not sure how to change existing code to incorporate that part.

Answer (score 0):

use a Queue instead of a list.

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue() #init
q.put('something') #put an element in the queue
q.put('something else') #put an element in the queue
print(q.get()) #get element from the queue

#you can itter through it also like ...
for val in iter(q.get, None):
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pool.map` call will return a list of responses:

```
response_list = pool.map(find_violations, file_list)
```

If you're just going to iterate over `response_list` and would like to start as soon as you have the first result, then you might be interested in the `pool.imap` function, which returns an iterable, rather than the full list.